# Jquery — Regex a URL slug into a capitalized sentence?

Tags: jquery, regex, string

Hi there
I'm trying to figure out how to convert

> this-is-my-slug

to:

> This Is My Slug

in Jquery?!

I know PHP is awesome with this, but jQuery maybe not?

Comment: Do you need the final text to actually be capitalized or just display as capitalized on the webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this works 100%:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y9WQC/1/

```
var string = "this-is-a-slug";

convert = string.replace(/-/g," ");

function ucwords (str) {
    // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
    // +   original by: Jonas Raoni Soares Silva (http://www.jsfromhell.com)
    // +   improved by: Waldo Malqui Silva
    // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
    // +   improved by: Robin
    // +      input by: James (http://www.james-bell.co.uk/)
    // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // *     example 1: ucwords('kevin van  zonneveld');
    // *     returns 1: 'Kevin Van  Zonneveld'
    // *     example 2: ucwords('HELLO WORLD');
    // *     returns 2: 'HELLO WORLD'
    return (str + '').replace(/^([a-z])|\s+([a-z])/g, function ($1) {
        return $1.toUpperCase();
    });
}
var result = ucwords(convert)
$("div").text(result); 

<div>my new string will output here</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you: **(This was a simple previous example)**

```
var str = "this-is-my-slug";
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/-/,' ').replace(/\b[a-z]/g, convert);
    function convert() {
          return arguments[0].toUpperCase();
    }
```

**Here it is in function form - the entire word and single word conversions:**

```
   //Converts and Formats entire string
   function Convert(test)
   {
       var formatted = test.toLowerCase().replace(/-/g,' ');
       var array = test.split(" ");
       var output = "";

       for (i=0;i<array.length;i++)
       {
              output += ConvertString(array[i]);
       }  
       return output;
    }

   //Formats individual words
   function ConvertString(string)
   {
       var str = string;
       str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/-/g,' ').replace(/\b[a-z]/g, convert);
       function convert() {
          return arguments[0].toUpperCase();
       }
       return str; 
   }
```

[Working Example - Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/wYTRV/2/)

Comment: No Problem - Hope it helped :)

Comment: Hmm just noticing one issue, it only replaces the first -, second third nth stay there. Guess I need to add a each() in there?

Comment: Oops I forgot the split - one sec :)

Comment: Actually, hmm, I'm trying this out again (in the jsfiddle) it doesn't work? I'm trying to figure out why but it's a bit beyond me, i'll keep trying though. Just to double check... my-dashed-string should output as My Dashed String, currently it's outputting My Dashed-String

Comment: It should all work now, i noticed an issue that I had forgotten the 'g' in the regular expressions (to indicate a global replace rather than just the first instance). Give it a shot now :)

Answer (score 0):

Comparing jQuery with PHP isn't a particularly fair comparison but rather than get into that I'll just direct you towards [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053902/how-to-convert-a-title-to-a-url-slug-in-jquery) question. It's doing the opposite operation but you might get some help with your issue from it.

Comment: You're right it's not a fair comparison. And I love jQuery :-)