# Create a stringToSlug() prototype function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053902/how-to-convert-a-title-to-a-url-slug-in-jquery) as an examples although I would prefer to write it like this: `value.stringToSlug()`

So I have changed it to this:

```
// String to slug
String.prototype.stringToSlug = function(str) {
      str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); // trim
      str = str.toLowerCase();
      str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '') // remove invalid chars
               .replace(/\s+/g, '-') // collapse whitespace and replace by -
               .replace(/-+/g, '-'); // collapse dashes
      return str;
};
```

It works if I pass the string like this:

```
var value = $(this).val();
value.stringToSlug(value);
```

Comment: Is there another way to get the value of the string without passing it as a param?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're modifying any prototype you can take advantage of the fact that `this` refers to the object itself; in this case it points to the string you're calling the method on:

```
String.prototype.stringToSlug = function() { // <-- removed the argument
    var str = this; // <-- added this statement

      str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); // trim
      str = str.toLowerCase();
      str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '') // remove invalid chars
               .replace(/\s+/g, '-') // collapse whitespace and replace by -
               .replace(/-+/g, '-'); // collapse dashes
      return str;
};
```

Then call like this:

```
$(this).val().stringToSlug();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question, but I'd also recommend against doing it.  There's no real advantage to doing it, and it makes your code somewhat less portable.

Comment: @Paul: What do you mean by "no advantage" and "less portable"?

Comment: @Paul I always have an uneasy feeling about extending prototypes of native objects in JavaScript :)

Comment: I mean, attaching it to the prototype of the String object isn't better than just making a regular function (or a function on your own object).  'less portable' was probably the wrong term, I just meant that if someone else sees his code, it's less intention-revealing, and potentially error prone if the code is broken into multiple files.  It's also generally considered a bad practice, as discussed here: http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/

Comment: @Jack: me too.  Brings back nightmares of the early days of the Prototype library.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Can't speak for Paul, but it mixes domain specific logic to a generic class; for instance, it wouldn't make sense that the string "Hello world" can be 'slugged' :)

Comment: @Paul I see exactly now where this could cause problems, maybe it would be better to do this in jquery `$.fn`? The main reason I wanted to do it this was over a stand alone function, was for readability of the code e.g so that it's possible to write it as a chain and thought the String would of been the best.

Comment: @JohnMagnolia: yeah, if you're going to use it a lot, I'd make it a jquery plugin as you suggest.