# Using django template tag inside javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I'm developing a project that have not any slug field and this value create in template by:

```
{{ n.title|slugify }}
```

I have to use slug an jquery code, but variable aleays empty:

```
$("select#model").click(function() {
      var u = $(this).find(":selected").val();
      var slg = $(this).find(":selected").text();
      var slug = "{{ slg|slugify }}";
      window.location.href("link that createt with u and slug);
   });
```

Is there anyway to using django template tag inside javascript?

Edit :

I have a queryset:

```
Model.objects.all()
```

How can I add manually field in this queryset?

Comment: What do you mean by "add manually field in this queryset"?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it inside the javascript.  Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053902/how-to-convert-a-title-to-a-url-slug-in-jquery) to slugify a text in the JS.

Comment: I have edited question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have to use django slugify.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the slug in the data attribute of your markup and then use javascript to grab it.

```
<select id="model">
   <option data-slug="{{ slg|slugify }}" ... this is inside your template
</select>


$("select#model").click(function() {
      var $opt = $(this).find(":selected")
      var u = $opt.val();
      var slug = $opt.data("slug");

      window.location.href("link that createt with u and slug);
   });
```