# How to custom sanitise a string so that it's suitable for a URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to sanitise strings of names (which may contain special characters) so that they are url friendly. For example a name may be:

```
The Red Hot Chili Peppers
A$AP Rocky
Christine & The Queens
Will.I.Am
```

These should be:

```
the-red-hot-chili-peppers
asap-rocky
christine-and-the-queens
will-i-am
```

Also other special characters like exclamation marks, slashes, dashes etc should be removed.

Is there a node module I can use to do this? How should I attempt this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Title to a URL slug in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053902/how-to-convert-a-title-to-a-url-slug-in-jquery)

Comment: In the code example you replaced `.` and spaces with dashes and then write "dashes should be removed".

Comment: Your example implies that "$" should be converted to uppercase "S",  "&" to "and", period and single space to dash.  But the answerer shouldn't have to compare your before-and-after example to extract the requirements; you should explicitly state them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const str = `The Red Hot Chili Peppers
A$AP Rocky
Christine & The Queens
Will.I.Am`;

const result =
  str
  .split("\n")
  .map(el => el
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/[$]|[ & ]+|[.]+|[ ]+/gi, x => x === '$' ? 's' : '-'))
  .join("\n");


console.log(result);
```

Comment: final .join should be  .join("\n")  instead of  .join("-").   I couldn't edit because the change is less than 6 characters.

Comment: it depends i think he what a string for an url so with .join("-") do the job he can changed it

Comment: OP's example *output* retained newlines from the *input*.  OP's requirements were vague, so you have to read between the lines (pun intended)